# sumar datos de una columna de una tabla obtenidos de una columna de otra tabla de mysql por identificador

Tags: mysql

tengo un dilema que me ha quitado el sueño y es cómo hago para sumar valores de columnas ubicados en dos tablas diferentes en mysql[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]. adjunto la idea general en una gráfica para que me puedan entender lo que estoy tratando de hacer. de antemano gracias por atender mi caso.

Comment: Pon la consulta que has hecho hasta ahora

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que las tablas están en la misma bbdd y que desconoces el como unir dos tablas.

Apoyándote en left,right,inner join ( lee sobre ellos para ver cuál se adapta a tus necesidades) podrás hacerlo directamente en la propia consulta

Sería algo como

```
SELECT SUM(t1.saldo, t2.saldo) from tabla1 as t1 left join tabla2 as t2  on t1.cedula = t2.cedula group by t1.cedula
```

Espero que no falle nada de la sintaxis, puesto que suelo trabajar con psql

Comment: Le falta la agrupación, sino va a sumar todo.

Comment: toda la razón, gracias

Comment: muchas a gracias a todos por sus prontas respuestas. Antonio tu sintaxis tiene mucho sentido y creo que se adapta a lo que quiero muchas gracias por tomarte tu tiempo y responder.